# How to render with transparent background in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Is it possible to render with transparent background using Eevee renderer?

Comment: In Film active the Transparent Box

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When using 2.79 you can find it on the right side in the properties section, go to render settings, scroll down to the film area and open it. In it, there is a dropdown box called alpha, and currently selected will be sky. Select transparent, and there you go!

[image]

In 2.80 the option has been changed to a checkbox and renamed to *Transparent* as shown in the image below.

[image: Blender 2.80 transparent background setting]

Comment: I dont have this Alpha option! BTW i use the most recent update version

Comment: What do I do if I checked the "Transparent" box but it's still not transparent?

Comment: Be sure you are also setting your export image settings to 'RGBA' instead of the default RGB, else your background will save as black.